# How do I remove JDK6 from my pi

Tags: raspbian, java

Im trying to install JDK version 7 on my raspberry pi, but when I try it keeps saying the current version is 1.6.0_34. How do I remove the old JDK to allow the new one to run?

Comment: how did you install the old version? Assuming you used apt-get you can do sudo apt-get purge package name or sudo apt-get remove package name. see this question for the difference between the 2 commands http://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove

Answer (score 3):

You can run these interactive commands to choose which Java-version that runs:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac  
sudo update-alternatives --config java  
sudo update-alternatives --config itweb-settings  
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

You can see all that may need to be changed using this command-line:

```
sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep jdk
```

This doesn't remove Java 6, but you can use `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre` to do that.

Comment: This also helps with changing the java version for rpi3 from 7 to 8.